# Issue making API request using logged in user's credentials

Tags: rest, github-api, next-auth, github-api-v3, trpc

I am using NextAuth and Github to authenticate a user in my app. I am trying to run a TRPC query to return an authenticated user's github repo information.

```
const response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/user`, {
      headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${account?.access_token}`,}
    });
```

1. The `access_token` is available - it logs out
2. The `access_token` is provided by NextAuth
3. Error Message: `documentation_url: "https://docs.github.com/rest" message: "Bad credentials"`

I am not sure exactly what I am doing wrong. When the user authenticates into my APP, I make sure to use `user` scope - and this is reflected under the `account.scope` property and Github Authentication UI.

I would appreciate some help, thank you !